# calling a custom function in a hibernate named query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I'm trying to call a function in a named query, but im getting :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node:     org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.MethodNode 
 \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'MYFUNCTION' {originalText=MYFUNCTION}
    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
       \-[NUM_INT] LiteralNode: '1'
```

and my query is something like

```
@NamedQuery(name = "myQuery",
            query = " select r, MYFUNCTION(r.id) from ResPO r "
                + " where  r.status like 'A'")
```

If I simplify my query, all is ok:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "myQuery",
        query = " select r from ResPO r "
            + " where  r.status like 'A'")
```

What is the mistake?
Thanks++

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by extending the dialect you're using and  registering your function by calling the `registerFunction()` method.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/dialect/Dialect.html#registerFunction%28java.lang.String,%20org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunction%29